# JS/jQuery: fire onchange from a disabled/readonly input without using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The goal is to get the total Qty for the whole year.

The user will input numbers into 3 different textboxes(Jan,Feb,Mar), then the sum will be displayed into a disabled textbox(Quarter1).
Now I have 4 instances of these knowing we have 4 quarters/year.

I can easily display the sum per quarter, by using the `onchange()` function attached to the textboxes.

Now I am having issues getting the sum from the 4 disabled textboxes, knowing we can't use the `onchange()` on it because it's disabled.

I have searched and probably getting results only when a button is used.

**TLDR**: I am trying to display the sum from the four disabled textboxes to another textbox automatically, without the user clicking any button(just like firing the `onchange` event)

I have tried this one, wherein I tried to display the value of the first quarter to the total, and not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[id$=yearlyTotal]').bind("displaytotal", function() {});
    $('#qtr1').change(function() {
        var mos = document.getElementsByClassName("quantityA");
        var mosCount = mos.length;
        var total = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < mosCount; i++) {
            total = total + parseInt(mos[i].value);
        }
        $('input[id$=yearlyTotal]').val(total).trigger('displaytotal');
    });
});
```

Hope it's possible, thanks in advance

EDIT: Added UI

Showing Q1 (its just the same for the 4 qtrs)

```
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Jan:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-2 small">
           <input type="number" min="0" id="col3" class="form-control input-sm monthly" data-q="q1" name="January"  />
           </div>
           <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Feb:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-2 small">
           <input type="number" min="0" id="col4" class="form-control input-sm monthly" data-q="q1" name="February" />
           </div>
           <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Mar:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-2 small">
           <input type="number" min="0" id="col5" class="form-control input-sm monthly" data-q="q1" name="March" />
           </div>
           <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Q1:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-2 small">
           <input type="text" min="0" id="q1" class="form-control input-sm quarter" name="q1"  style="background-color: #b3dcf5;"  disabled />
           </div>
</div>
```

This is the div for the total Qty

```
<div class="col-md-6">
       <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" id="">Total Quantity:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-3 small">
       <input type="text" id="final" class="form-control input-sm" name="TotalQuantity" value="0" disabled />
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1:

Basically, what you need to do is to trigger the **`change`** event for the disabled quarter fields *programatically*, using jQuery [**`.trigger()`**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function.

As I don't know how your HTML is structured -*this why it is always recommended to provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example*- I made a demo example and I've done things differently, like below:

[**jsFiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/ros9tdd8/)

```js
var monthly = $('.monthly'),
  Qrt = $('.quarter');

monthly.on('change, input', function() {
  var $th = $(this),
    // depending on the value of the data-q attribute, we pick
    // all input fields with the same data-q as an array, then
    //loop through them adding their values up
    q = $th.attr('data-q'),
    qArray = $th.parent().children('input[data-q="' + q + '"]'),
    tempSum = 0;

  for (var i = 0, ln = qArray.length; i < ln; i++) {
    tempSum += +$(qArray[i]).val();
  }
  
  // we pick the corresponding quarter sum field, again depending
  // on the value of the data-q attritues, and update its value, then
  // we trigger the change event of this quarter sum field.
  $('#' + q).val(tempSum).trigger('change'); // here you trigger it
});

Qrt.on('change', function() {
  var qSum = 0;
  for (var i = 0, ln = Qrt.length; i < ln; i++) {
    qSum += +$(Qrt[i]).val();
  }
  $('#final').val(qSum);
});
```

```css
.monthly { width: 32%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Grand Total:</h3><input type="text" id="final" disabled><hr>
<h3>1st Q:</h3>
<input type="text" class="monthly" data-q="q1">
<input type="text" class="monthly" data-q="q1">
<input type="text" class="monthly" data-q="q1">
<br>Sum:<input id="q1" type="text" class="quarter" disabled>
<h3>2nd Q:</h3>
<input type="text" class="monthly" data-q="q2">
<input type="text" class="monthly" data-q="q2">
<input type="text" class="monthly" data-q="q2">
<br>Sum:<input id="q2" type="text" class="quarter" disabled>
<h3>3rd Q:</h3>
<input type="text" class="monthly" data-q="q3">
<input type="text" class="monthly" data-q="q3">
<input type="text" class="monthly" data-q="q3">
<br>Sum:<input id="q3" type="text" class="quarter" disabled>
<h3>4th Q:</h3>
<input type="text" class="monthly" data-q="q4">
<input type="text" class="monthly q-4th" data-q="q4">
<input type="text" class="monthly q-4th" data-q="q4">
<br>Sum:<input id="q4" type="text" class="quarter" disabled>
```

---

#### Method 2:

since any change you make to any **`.monthly`** field will change the corresponding value of quarter sum, and thus it'll also affect the value of the yearly sum, you don't need to capture the **`change`** event of the disabled quarter sum fields, just loop through their values and update the value of the yearly field, all should be done inside the **`on('change')`** event of the **`.monthly`** fields, like below:

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/ros9tdd8/1/)

**jQuery**

```js
var monthly = $('.monthly'),
    Qrt = $('.quarter');

monthly.on('change, input', function() {
  var $th = $(this),
    q = $th.attr('data-q'),
    qArray = $th.parent().children('input[data-q="' +q+ '"]'),
    tempSum = 0,
    qSum = 0;

  for (var i = 0, ln = qArray.length; i < ln; i++) {
    tempSum += +$(qArray[i]).val();
  }
  $('#' + q).val(tempSum);
  
  // code below
  for (var i = 0, ln = Qrt.length; i < ln; i++) {
    qSum += +$(Qrt[i]).val();
  }
  $('#final').val(qSum);
});
```

---

#### Update:

For the updated HTML in the OP, replace `qArray` line with this one:

```
$th.parents('.form-group').find('input[data-q="' + q + '"]')`,
```

*Note* [**`parents()`**](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) is with "s" letter, unlike the former `parent()` which moves up a single level up the DOM, it does " *search through the ancestors of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements ordered from immediate parent on up.* ", so it travels up until we reach the matchng parent, here it is `.form-group`.

Then instead of `children()`, we use [**`find()`**](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

[**jsFiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/ros9tdd8/3/)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks I will definitely study this code and i'll keep in mind about the MCVE. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: got a little problem here, I believe the qArray is suppose to get the 3 input values from one parent. and in my case, it only gets one because every input is within it's own div (for design purposes kindly check the question i have added the HTML)  anything you can suggest? thanks!

Comment: You welcome and yes you are right, it's the `qArray`, because of `parent()` only moves up one level, use `parents()` with a selector and `find()` instead of `children()`, check the *Update*  section in my answer

Comment: Great! It's working perfectly now, thanks for the help again :)

Answer (score -1):

**Please find the below code (Finding the total for quarter A & quarter B) for your reference. Please use same methodology for other quarters.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
/* FINDING THE QUARTER A AND QUARTER B */
function findingQuaterTotal () {
      /* LOADING QUARTER A AND FINDING ITS TOTAL - STARTS */
      var mosQuarterA = document.getElementsByClassName("quarterA"),
          mosCountQuarterA = mosQuarterA.length,
          totalQuarterA = 0,
          i = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < mosCountQuarterA; i++) {
          totalQuarterA = totalQuarterA + parseInt(mosQuarterA[i].value);
      }
      /* ADDING INTO QUATER A DISABLED TEXTBOX */
      $("#quarterA").val(totalQuarterA);
      /* LOADING QUARTER A AND FINDING ITS TOTAL - ENDS */

      /* LOADING QUARTER B AND FINDING ITS TOTAL - STARTS */
      var mosQuarterB = document.getElementsByClassName("quarterB"),
          mosCountQuarterB = mosQuarterB.length,
          totalQuarterB = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < mosCountQuarterB; i++) {
          totalQuarterB = totalQuarterB + parseInt(mosQuarterB[i].value);
      }
      /* ADDING INTO QUARTER B DISABLED TEXTBOX */
      $("#quarterB").val(totalQuarterB);
      /* LOADING QUARTER B AND FINDING ITS TOTAL - ENDS */

      /* TRIGGERING CHANGE EVENT IN THE DISABLED TEXTBOX WHOSE ID STARTS WITH QUARTER.*/
      $("input[id^='quarter']").trigger("change");
};

/* ABOVE CHANGE TRIGGER WILL CALL BELOW EVENTS - STARTS */
$("input[id^='quarter']").change(function () {                        $("#final").val(parseInt($("#quarterA").val())+parseInt($("#quarterB").val()));
});
/* ABOVE CHANGE TRIGGER WILL CALL BELOW EVENTS - ENDS */

/* IF ANY VALUE CHANGES IN MONTH TEXT BOX, FLLWING FUNCTION WILL BE CALLED - STARTS */
$("input[id^='month']").on("change keyup",function () {
  findingQuaterTotal();
});
findingQuaterTotal();
/* IF ANY VALUE CHANGES IN MONTH TEXT BOX, FLLWING FUNCTION WILL BE CALLED - ENDS */  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Quater A</h2>
Jan - <input type="number" id="month1" value="6" class="quarterA"></br>
Feb - <input type="number" id="month2" value="16" class="quarterA"></br>
March - <input type="number" id="month3" value="25" class="quarterA"></br>
Quater A Total - <input type="number" id="quarterA" value="" disabled></br>

<br/><br/>
<h2>Quater B</h2>
April - <input type="number" id="month4" value="6" class="quarterB"></br>
May - <input type="number" id="month5" value="16" class="quarterB"></br>
June - <input type="number" id="month6" value="25" class="quarterB"></br>
Quater B Total - <input type="number" id="quarterB" value="" disabled></br>


Quarter A and Quarter B total - <input type="number" id="final" value="" disabled>
</body>
</html>
```