# Auto-populate input text field based on value in another input field that is set to readonly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I'm hoping someone can assist me with the issue I'm having. I'm trying to automatically populate a price (input text) field based on the value that is auto-populated in the categoryname (input text) field. I know how to use the onchange function as I am successfully using it on numerous other elements in my php page. However, this one is a bit more challenging because both of the fields are read only. Also, the use of a button is not an option in this situation, thus the reason a number of the other posts related to my problem did not work for me.

I have tried the following: 
[Set dropdown value based on what is selected in another dropdown using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203800/set-dropdown-value-based-on-what-is-selected-in-another-dropdown-using-javascrip?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), [jQuery's change() event doesn't work as expected with input text fields. This, however, does work.](https://gist.github.com/brandonaaskov/1596867#file-jquery-change-event-proper-binding), [Text changed event of a readonly textbox](https://forums.asp.net/t/1088494.aspx?Text%20changed%20event%20of%20a%20readonly%20textbox) , [JS/jQuery: fire onchange from a disabled/readonly input without using button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973681/js-jquery-fire-onchange-from-a-disabled-readonly-input-without-using-button?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), and about 10 others. Unfortunately, as I mentioned none of the code scenarios I tried from those posts worked for me. (Ex. bind, input, trigger, etc.)

Here is the code I currently have in place (still not working):
**PHP**

```
echo '<td align="left" width="8%" height="25px">';
        $ddlquery4 = "SELECT * FROM dvd ORDER BY title ASC";
        $ddlresult4 = mysqli_query($dbc, $ddlquery4) or die("Bad SQL: $ddlquery4");
        echo '<select type="text" class="dropdown" name="dvdid" id="movieID" size="1" onchange="updatecat()">';
        echo '<option value=""></option>';
        while($ddlrow4=mysqli_fetch_array($ddlresult4, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option value='".$ddlrow4['dvdid']."' data-categoryname='".$ddlrow4['categoryname']."'>" . $ddlrow4['title'] . "</option>";
        } //End while statement

        echo "</select>";
        echo '</a></td>';
        echo '<td align="left" width="5%">';
        echo '<input style="font-size:20px; border:0px; background:none; box-shadow:none;" type="text" id="catName" name="categoryname" readonly="readonly" onchange="popprice()">';

    echo '<td align="left" width="4%">';
        '<input type="text" id="catprice" name="price" readonly="readonly">';
```

**JS/jquery**

```
<script>
$('#movieID').change(function() {
    selectedOption = $('option:selected', this);
    $('input[id=catName]').val( selectedOption.data('categoryname') );
 });
</script>

<script>
$('#catName').bind('change', function() {
   if (document.getElementById('catName').value == 'Regular')
    document.getElementById('catprice').value = '.50';
      else if (document.getElementById('catName').value == 'Popular')
        document.getElementById('catprice').value = '1.00';
      else if (document.getElementById('catName').value == 'Current Release')
        document.getElementById('catprice').value = '1.50';
      else if (document.getElementById('catName').value == 'Current Hit')
        document.getElementById('catprice').value = '2.00';
});
</script>
```

**A SMALL SAMPLE OF THE NUMEROUS OTHER SCENARIOS I'VE TRIED:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('popprice').change(function() {
    selectedOption = $('option:selected', .data('categoryname');
    if $(categorynameValue).val('Regular') {
        ('#catprice').val('.50');
        }
    else if $(categorynameValue).val('Popular') {
        ('#catprice').val('1.00');
        }
    else if $(categorynameValue).val('Current Release') {
        ('#catprice').val('1.50');
        }
    else if $(categorynameValue).val('Current Hit') {
        ('#catprice').val('2.00');
        }
    else ('#catprice').val("");
});
});
</script>
```

With the popprice added to the updatecat change function in the select line like this:

```
echo '<td align="left" width="8%" height="25px">';
        $ddlquery4 = "SELECT * FROM dvd ORDER BY title ASC";
        $ddlresult4 = mysqli_query($dbc, $ddlquery4) or die("Bad SQL: $ddlquery4");
        echo '<select type="text" class="dropdown" name="dvdid" id="movieID" size="1" onchange="updatecat(); popprice();">';
        echo '<option value=""></option>';
        while($ddlrow4=mysqli_fetch_array($ddlresult4, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option value='".$ddlrow4['dvdid']."' data-categoryname='".$ddlrow4['categoryname']."'>" . $ddlrow4['title'] . "</option>";
        } //End while statement
```

And I've tried combining the if elseif statements within the #movieID change function like this and only left onchange="updatecat();" in the select element:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#movieID').change(function() {
    selectedOption = $('option:selected', this);
    $('input[id=catName]').val(selectedOption.data('categoryname') );

    var selectedOption = $('option:selected', .data('categoryname') );
    if $(categorynameValue).val('Regular') {
        ('#catprice').val('.50');
        }
    else if $(categorynameValue).val('Popular') {
        ('#catprice').val('1.00');
        }
    else if $(categorynameValue).val('Current Release') {
        ('#catprice').val('1.50');
        }
    else if $(categorynameValue).val('Current Hit') {
        ('#catprice').val('2.00');
        }
    else ('#catprice').val("");
});
});
</script>
```

I've also tried this within the movieID change function script...

```
if ('#catName' = 'Regular') {
        document.getElementByID("catprice".innerHTML = ".05"
    } else if ('#catName' = 'Popular') {
        document.getElementByID("catprice".innerHTML = "1.00"
    } else if ('#catName' = 'Current Release'){
        document.getElementByID("catprice".innerHTML = "1.50"
    } else if ('#catName' = 'Current Hit'){
        document.getElementByID("catprice".innerHTML = "2.00"
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance for your time and sharing your knowledge.

Comment: If `catName` is `readonly`, how could its `change` event be triggered? If its initial value is `""`, it'll stay that way, right? When is `catName` intended to be changed?

Comment: do you really need to populate a form field at all? why not just display the catName value as text? if its not user editable it does not belong in a form input

Comment: catName changes when a selection is made in the dropdown element just before it that also has an onchange function set to it. That one is working well and auto-populating the catName field as it should, the issue is that since the catName field is set to read only, it has no clue when it changes and therefore doesn't trigger the onchange function set on it. Thus the reason it doesn't auto-populate the price field. I'm wondering if there is a way to force the program to make catName recognize when it changes?

Comment: `when a selection is made in the dropdown element` This sounds extremely relevant to the question - post the code in an edit to your question to make it clear where the changes are originating from.

Comment: so trigger of dropdown for both

Comment: @CertainPerformance That is the question I need anwered, "How could its change event be triggered?". Also, I see what you are saying about the value "". Thanks. I didn't notice that I had forgotten to take that out of that line, but it does work either way. I'm not sure how. ;)  I'm just happy that it does.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I updated the code in my question to include the dropdown that catName is being generated from.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  Your faster than I am. ;) It should be posted now.

Comment: What is `updatecat`? That's the part that (tries) to assign to the first read-only element, so fixing that is part of the issue here. Probably, just have `updatecat` call the other function

Comment: as  above and if your going to use jquery, fully use it `('#catName').val()` instead of `document.getElementById('catName').value`

Comment: @smith That would not achieve anything

Comment: use a language as its intended would not archive anything?

Comment: @smith That would be the ideal thing to do, and I tried and tried to do just that, but the tables have a one to many relationship. I couldn't come up with a query that provided me with the columns I needed from the 'foreign key' table (dvd) AND included the columns from the table with the primary key (paymethod). The dvd.categoryname column is fed from the paymethod.categoryname column. Neither joins or unions gave me what I needed.

Comment: @smith  That shows my lack of knowledge between jquery and javascript. I'm learning, but it is taking time.

Comment: @smith Using jQuery instead of the built-in DOM manipulation methods for setting the value of an element doesn't change anything relevant to the problem here. No-library JS methods are perfectly fine (and often preferable).

Comment: @CertainPerformance You are correct, updatecat is the onchange function that is populating the value into the catName field. It is for reference purposes only - it doesn't post to the server. If I could add the other code to the updatecat script, that would be the ideal way to go. I just couldn't get anything to work. Is it possible to add my if and elseif statements to it? Maybe I just wasn't using the proper syntax.

Comment: `I just couldn't get anything to work` Then post the relevant code in the question and we can try to start debugging. Without being able to see the code you're trying there, it's quite hard to say exactly what the problem is there or what the best solution would be.

Comment: I've tried at least 15 different scenarios. Do you want me to post them all? Based on my experience from a similar situation that proved unsuccessful, I'm almost 100% certain that the reason this isn't working is because my catName field is set to readonly. However, from what I learned on a couple of the posts (links included in my question), others have made it work. I'm fairly certain that calling this onchange function within my #movieID one will make it work and be much easier, but I'm not sure about the syntax required to do that. Can I just put it inside the curly brackets?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Per your request, I added some of the other things I've tried to my question. I think my best option is to add the script for this within the existing script for the movieID change function. However, whenever I try this it causes the updatecat() to quit working, so I know I don't have the text and syntax right. This is one of the samples included. Will you please take a look and let me know if you see anything wrong?